# Two Separate SharePoint Instances in one domain?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dns, sharepoint-2013

I currently have SharePoint Foundations 2010 set up in our network.  I have been directed to bring up SharePoint Foundations 2013 for a separate project.  We would then slowly migrate all data to SharePoint 2013.  Is it possible to have two completely separate SharePoint instances in one domain?  Assuming of course that they would each be on their own front end server and sql database servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have any number of instances of SharePoint in the same domain. It will not be an issue.
JD

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have two instances of SharePoint, but the urls need to be slightly different, just as the servers need to have different names.

That's not a bad strategy for upgrading if you don't have gobs of content that would have to be moved over right away.

Here's an example, if your domain is xyz.com and your first sharepoint server uses xyz.com, you could set your second instance up as sharepoint.xyz.com

You would just need to make sure you had dns set up to point sharepoint.xyz.com to your second server's ip address.